# How to get the myget package source?

Tags: nuget, myget

I am using myget for my Nuget packages. Because i am using a private feed with credentials, i followed this blog: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/deploying-to-azure-web-sites-using-nuget-package-restore-from-a-secured-feed

My local (project) nuget.config (located in the .nuget folder in the solution) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSource>
    <clear />

    <add key="EcareMyGet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/rai69/"></add>

  </packageSource>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="EcareMyGet" value="https://www.myget.org/F/rai69/"></add>
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <EcareMyGet>
      <add key="Username" value="www.myget.org/raimond" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="wachtwoord" />
    </EcareMyGet>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

In my nuget.targets i've changed the restore command according to the blog:

```
<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)"   -NonInteractive   $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDir)\" -Verbosity detailed </RestoreCommand>
```

Despite this, the buildserver is still using nuget.org as source:

```
NuGet.exe sources
  Registered Sources:

    1.  https://nuget.org/api/v2/ [Enabled]
        https://nuget.org/api/v2/
```

Who knows a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer: replace <packageSource> by <packageSources> in the nuget.config file**

*Below is the conversation that lead to the answer...*

Just to be sure, did you also read the part where you disable the -RequireConsent switch?

```
<RequireRestoreConsent Condition=" '$(RequireRestoreConsent)' != 'false' ">
false
</RequireRestoreConsent>
```

Also, make sure you didn't configure it in the MSBuild PackageSources element, which by default looks as shown below (no package source configured):

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
    <!-- Package sources used to restore packages. 
         By default, registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config 
         will be used -->
    <!-- The official NuGet package source (https://nuget.org/api/v2/) will be 
         excluded if package sources are specified and it does not appear 
         in the list -->
    <!--
        <PackageSource Include="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <PackageSource Include="https://my-nuget-source/nuget/" />
    -->
</ItemGroup>
```

If you did and that's not the issue, can you please share a little more detail about the output logs so I can determine when the issue is caused and by what command?

Comment: I did both. I can send you the original files if you want

Comment: Feel free to send them to support@myget.org, we'll take a closer look at it.

Comment: Found the bug in your nuget.config file... It is <packageSources>, not <packageSource> :-)

Answer (score 0):

You write that you use *"My local (project) nuget.config"*, which makes me believe that you have the *nuget.config* file located in your project folder.

You can read about the [NuGet Config File here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file). There you'll see that *"NuGet first loads NuGet.config from the default location, then loads any file named NuGet.config starting from the root of the current drive and ending in the current directory."*.

What this means, it that NuGet will look for the configuration in the folder hierarchy all the way from the root and to the location of *nuget.exe*, which usually is under the *.nuget* folder in the solution root. This means that it will never look inside the project folders in your solution. So you can try to move your *nuget.config* to the solution folder, and see it it gets read properly then.

Comment: My local (project) nuget.config is located in .nuget folder within the solution.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the *nuget.exe* file that is inside the *.nuget* folder? Because if you're at your solution root when typing `nuget`, it will probably use the *nuget.exe* that's found in the PATH defined in your environment variables, and it will then not find your custom config file. What happens if you go inside the *.nuget* folder and explicitly run the *nuget.exe* located there? Does it then use the correct config values?